# How to (re)install ca-bundle.crt

Tags: amazon-linux

When I tried to install packages, I encountered the following problem

```
[Errno 14] curl#77 - "error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none"
```

It is mainly because I accidentally deleted `ca-bundle.crt` prevously. I wonder how to reinstall `ca-bundle.crt`.

If someone has opinion for undoing, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo yum reinstall ca-certificates
```